# How can i delay Visibilty anmation in flutter? like wait 2 seconds then begin animation

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I dont mean delay the animation but like wait for 2 secs after my route is drawn on my google map then start the animation, so it would delay for like 3 secs then begin animation

```
Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,

  child: 

  Visibility (
  visible : showCancelButton, 
  child : Container(


         height:50,
                    width: 50, margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 100,bottom: 20,right: 10),

                    child: Align (alignment: Alignment.topRight,

         child: new FloatingActionButton(onPressed:clearMyMap,
             heroTag: "btn1",
         tooltip: "Cancel Trip",
         backgroundColor:Colors.white,
         child: Icon(Icons.cancel, color:Colors.black,),
         ),
                    )
      )
  )

),
```

Answer (score 0):

in GoogleMap widget:

```
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          _controller.complete(controller);
          // wait for 3secs
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: e), () {});
          // showCancelButton = true and setState
        },
```